# grid view to adding row dynamicaly, but getting blank value while inserting

Tags: c#, asp.net

recently I changed my GridView so it was able to add rows dynamically. The problem is, when I insert the data, I'm getting blank value at first.

I'm unable to get the details of my labels.text , but are able to get the text box value the first time. When the loop continues, I get 1 row  of value from the label and 2 rows of value from the text box.

```
GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

    TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
    cell.Text = "Details";
    cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
    row.Controls.Add(cell);


    cell = new TableHeaderCell();
    cell.Text = "Year 2018";
    cell.ColumnSpan = 4;
    row.Controls.Add(cell);

    cell = new TableHeaderCell();
    cell.ColumnSpan = 4;
    cell.Text = "Year 2019";
    row.Controls.Add(cell);

     cell = new TableHeaderCell();
    cell.Text = "Others";
    cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
    row.Controls.Add(cell);
```

and here is submit code..

```
Label CenterId = (Label)row.FindControl("CenterId") as Label;
              string CenterId_no = Convert.ToString(CenterId.Text);


          //  Label lbl_lastyear_beforedate = (Label)row.FindControl("lbl_lastyear_beforedate") as Label;

      //  float  PY_Bdte = float.Parse(lbl_lastyear_beforedate.Text);


            TextBox txt_lastyearonDate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_lastyearonDate") as TextBox;

            float py_ondte = float.Parse(txt_lastyearonDate.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by adding a `DataRow` for all columns of `GridView` at time of binding:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["col1"] = 0;
dr["col2"] = 0;
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
```

And at time of submitting code:

```
if (row.RowIndex>0)
{
    // getting the all values and inserted..
}
```